# Can we connect Google App-Script to Google Cloud SQL (MySQL) just only private ip enable?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a trouble about connect Google App script to Google Cloud SQL,
It  worked fine when I enable public IP for cloud SQL instance, but when I disable public IP and just only enable private IP, It can't connect and show error "Failed with an error Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password."

My customer don't want to enabler public IP.
Please help me :(